# How to get SQL Script using Entity Framework Core(code first)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm create a web app using Asp.net core with EntityFramework core, but the Update-Database command no longer has the "-Script" switch. How can I get the sql script? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this command to produce the SQL Script

```
> dotnet ef migrations script -o fileName.sql
```

Also there's a powershell command for it too: [powershell#script-migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#script-migration)

Comment: For me it does not work. I am getting a file with just the 
`IF OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;

GO`. While I also have a few entities setup. Maybe you know I may be missing?

Comment: It has `from` and `to` parameters too. Try to specify them explicitly.

Comment: The problem was that first before executing the command I had to generate migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I come at this question to find command that can generate script for all tables/db objects from dbcontext. If you are also looking same instead of just migration or update, command is :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext script -o filename.sql
```

Just open the command prompt in folder in which entity framework exist & run this. this will create SQL file in same folder.

Just make sure you have dotnet ef tools installed, if not already use

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

before the above context command.